# Passing data from Siri to other apps in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios10, siri, sirikit

We are implementing `Sirikit` for one of our application. We are able to send message using `SiriKit` intent `INSendMessageIntent`. Upon `“Send” Siri` command handling, we need to pass some of the information to other application.
We have figured out `[self.extensionContext openURL]` to open application from `intentViewController`. As we observed that, there is `configureWithInteraction` of `IntentViewController` which gets called every time `Siri` processes each user command. Since we need to open application only on `“Send” Siri` command, we are not able to identify current processing state i.e. “Send”.

OR is there anyway to call `openURL` from `intentHandler`?

We are completing IntentResponse as mentioned below.

```
NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@“com.xxxxxx.xxx.myapp”];

INSendMessageIntentResponse *response = [[INSendMessageIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendMessageIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:userActivity];
NSLog(@"response is %@",response);
completion(response);
```

We are expecting following function from containing app’s delegate to be called when action gets completed (i.e.INSendMessageIntentResponse is passed to completion handler)

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
```

Comment: Hi @jamesraj. Did you find the solution. is it possible to pass data to the application via siri.

Comment: Hi @V.J. did you found any solution for sending data from siri extension (INSendMessageIntent) to application.

Answer (score 0):

Several years passed ... but anyway, maybe it will help someone.
You can pass parameters with user activity you created.

[userActivity addUserInfoEntries:  ]